# Issue with Gravatar not showing when using several Stack Exchange "Logins" email accounts

Tags: support, bug, gravatar

I use several "Logins" via Google to access Stack Exchange sites and I had previously uploaded from my computer a picture as avatar.

Recently I used Gravatar for **ONE** "Login" email associated with my account.

Now when in "Edit your profile" and click text "Change Picture" I see only options "Uploaded pictures" and "Identicon" but I do **NOT** see Gravatar image/option.

I would like to use Gravatar in my Stack Exchange account and keep in Gravatar register only one email.

I have tried, to refresh the browser cache and wait some time for SE cache to renew with no result. My picture for Gravatar show up on other sites but not on SE.

Is a bug in the application? Or could you please tell me how to setup Gravatar when using multiple "Logins".